# BigQuery SQL: How to find missing Values on comparing two tables over date range?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, left-join, missing-data

Have got two Bigquery tables as shown below:

**Table 1:**

```
Store   Report_Date
11      2021-03-03
12      2021-03-03
11      2021-04-14
13      2021-04-14
```

**Table 2:**

```
Store
11
12
13
```

**Scenario:**
Have to find missing Stores of Table 1 for each date comparing with Table 2 Stores.

**Expected Output:**
To list each missing Stores for each date on comparing.

```
MissingStore    Report_Date     
13              2021-03-03
12              2021-04-14
```

**Tried Query:**
But this query doesn't shows up the respective Report_Date, instead it shows 'null'.

```
 WITH
      tab1 AS (
      SELECT
        DISTINCT Store,
        Report_Date
      FROM
        tab1
        )
      
    SELECT
      DISTINCT tab2.Store, tab1.Report_Date
    FROM
      tab2
    LEFT JOIN
      tab1
    ON
      tab1.Store = tab2.Store
    WHERE  
      tab1.Store IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a calendar table approach:

```sql
SELECT s.Store AS MissingStore, d.Report_Date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Store FROM tab1) s
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Report_Date FROM tab1) d
INNER JOIN tab2 t2
    ON s.Store = t2.Store
LEFT JOIN tab1 t1
    ON t1.Store = s.Store AND t1.Report_Date = d.Report_Date
WHERE t1.Store IS NULL;
```

Comment: I think some error with query.. your Left joining table 's' doesn't hold report_date. Can you correct the query. Thanks!

Comment: @user12345 I have corrected the error, thanks.

Comment: Worked fine with little change. Replaced tab1 with tab2 in 's'

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select a.Store MissingStore, b.Report_Date
from table2 a
cross join (select distinct Report_Date from table1) b
left join table1 c
using(Store, Report_Date)
where c.Report_Date is null
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]